# Make an enemy walk around a rectangular platform, like in Metroid

Tags: c#

I'm new to Unity, so probably this is a dumb question but I have several days trying to figure it out. I have an enemy walking from one side of a platform to the other. I'm using Raycasting to check if there´s no ground below and turn to the other way.

What I want is for the enemy to walk AROUND the platform (Just like the enemies in Metroid). I set the gravity of the enemy to 0 so it will not fall down, but I don´t know how to make it rotate and keep walking around the platform. I know it could be done with raycasting but I have not clue how to do it.

I will enormously appreciated if anyone can help me with the piece of code I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

```
public class BlobController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    float myWidth;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myWidth = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().bounds.extents.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Check to see if there's ground in front before moving forward

        Vector2 lineCasPos = transform.position - transform.right * myWidth;
        Debug.DrawRay (lineCasPos, Vector2.down,Color.red);
        bool isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast (lineCasPos, Vector2.down, 2, groundMask);

        //If there's no ground, turn around

        if (!isGrounded) 
        {
            Vector3 currRot = transform.eulerAngles;
            currRot.y += 180;
            transform.eulerAngles = currRot;
        }

        //Always move forward

        Vector2 myVel = myRigidBody.velocity;
        myVel.x = -transform.right.x * moveSpeed;
        myRigidBody.velocity = myVel;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to cycle through pairs representing direction in which to move and direction in which to raycast (`transform.right` and `Vector2.down`). E.g. if the object is moving cw, `transform.right` and `Vector2.down` need to be substituted with `transform.down` and `Vector2.left` when you run out of ground.

Comment: Have you tried changing `currRot.y += 180;` to `currRot.y += 90;` and using `transform.down` instead of `Vector2.down`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Zong, can you please add a pseudo code?

Comment: I just don´t know how to implement it.

Comment: My isGrounded boolean is equal to = Physics2D.Raycast (lineCasPos, Vector2.down, 2, groundMask);, how can I change it to Physics2D.Raycast (lineCasPos, Vector2.right, 2, groundMask); when, for example, the object transform.rotation.z == 90? I need a boolean array of different raycastings? I'm stuck here.

Comment: I just did it. In the most inelegant way with 133 lines of code but is working perfectly fine. :)

Comment: What I don't understand is, why not use `transform.down` instead of `Vector2.down`? When you rotate the `transform` 90 degrees, the `down` direction should rotate with it.